# Приходит пустой post запрос ajax+django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post, xmlhttprequest

После нажатия на кнопку отправляется post запрос:

**ajax.js:**

```js
document.querySelector("#ajaxbtn1").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr1.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/", true);
        xhr1.send("TEXT");

        xhr1.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr1.status != 200) {
            alert(xhr1.status + ": " + xhr1.statusText);
        } 
        else {
            alert("Uploaded!");
            console.log(xhr1.responseText);
        };
    };
})
```

Так же после отправки я вывожу в консоль responseText. 
В консоль выводится html, там всё отображается как надо. А именно нужна эта строчка: `<p>b&#39;TEXT&#39;</p>`
Но при открытии файла ajax.html(на который посылается запрос) вместо нужной строки, там отображается: `b''`

**views.py:**

```py
@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request):
    get_value = request.body
    return render(request, "blog/ajax.html", context = {"val": get_value})
```

**ajax.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{val}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Или так всё и должно быть, тогда как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку и перехода на страницу ajax.html в строчке было: "TEXT"?

**В консоли никаких ошибок нет**

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное. Если Вы хотите передавать данные через `Ajax`, то лучше будет делать это с помощью `Json` ([`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)).

Comment: @nomnoms12, если не сложно, можете подсказать как реализовать самый простой запрос с помощью json, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация `json`-ответа:

***views.py***

```py
from django.views import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
from datetime import datetime


class TestView(View):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        # Здесь Вы обрабатываете запрос и формируете ответ
        data = {
            'time': datetime.now(),
        }

        return JsonResponse(data)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        # Здесь Вы обрабатываете запрос и формируете ответ
        data = {
            'time': datetime.now(),
            'comment': "It's response to POST request",
        }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

***urls.py:***

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', TestView.as_view()),
]
```

---

`JavaScript` на стороне клиента (используя `jQuery`):

```js
// Пример запроса без передачи данных
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/test/', function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

После этого в консоли напечатается время, которое вернул сервер. Примерно так:

```js
{time: "2019-07-18T16:47:17.413"}
```

---

Следует уточнить, что `POST` запросы делать сложнее. Требуется также передавать `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.

***ajax.html:***

```html
...
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
<script type="text/javascript">
    let csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
</script>
...
```

---

`JavaScript` на стороне клиента (используя `jQuery`):

```js
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: C get всё работает, но с post - нет. В js: `$.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/", {"smth": 1}, function(data){
 console.log(data)
})`Ошибка я так полагаю в views.py:`def postView(request):
    data = request.POST
    return JsonResponse(data)`Как отправленные json данные следует обрабатывать в django? При переходе на страницу куда отправляется запрос отображается пустой словарь.

Comment: @SchMelz_ Я не добавлял обработчик `POST`-запроса Сейчас добавлю для примера, если Вам нужно.

Comment: да, не откажусь

Comment: @SchMelz_ Уже сделано :) Для того чтобы отличить ответы, я добавил к `POST` дополнительную строчку.