# Как отправить из js Json на python(Django) и как уже обработать то что отправил

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

views.py(куда отправляю):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
# Create your views here.
def first_page(request):
    return render (request,'jg/firstpage.html')

def about_us(request):
    return render (request,'jg/about_page.html')

def reviews(request):
    return render(request,'jg/reviews.html')

def create(request):
    return render(request,'jg/create.html')
```

script:

```
<script>
    {% block scripts %}
        let a=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        let b=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        let c =document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        b.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if ( a.value !='' && c.value !=''){
                name={name:a.value};
                content={content:c.value};
                var jnameurl=name.JSON.stringify(name);
                var jcontenturl-content.JSON.stringify(content);
                var jname= new XMLHttpRequest();
                var jcontent = new XMLHttpRequest();
                jname.open('GET',jnameurl,views.py);
                jcontent.open('GET',jcontenturl,views.py);
                jname.responseType = 'json';
                jcontent.responseType = 'json';
                jname.send();
                jcontent.send();

            }
            else {
            alert('you not write to input ');
            }
        });
    {% endblock scripts %}
</script>
```

Правильно ли я отправил данные и как мне их принять уже в python , мб кто-то подскажет.

Comment: А что у вас за 3-й аргумент в `open`?

Comment: тут я уже сам исправил

Comment: Можете помочь с другим вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013819/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-jname-status-%d0%b8-jcontent-status-0

Comment: ну так исправьте в самом вопросе

Comment: Посмотрите [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1004342/339283), возможно он Вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let a=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        let b=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        let c =document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        b.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if ( a.value !='' && c.value !=''){
                let name=a.value;
                let content=c.value;
                console.log(name);
                console.log(content);
                let jnameurl=JSON.stringify(name);
                let jcontenturl=JSON.stringify(content);
                let jname= new XMLHttpRequest();
                let jcontent = new XMLHttpRequest();
                jname.open('POST',jnameurl,'server.php',true);
                jcontent.open('POST',jcontenturl,'server.php',true);;
                jname.send(jnameurl);
                jcontent.send(jcontenturl);
                console.log(jname.status);
                console.log(jcontent.status);
                console.log(jname.statusText);
                console.log(jcontent.statusText);
                console.log(jname.responseText);
                console.log(jcontent.responseText);
            }
            else {
            alert('you not write to input ');
            }
        });
```