# Почему jname.status и jcontent.status ==0?

Tags: javascript, php, json

скрипт (данные я получаю нормально):

```
        let a=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        let b=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        let c =document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        b.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if ( a.value !='' && c.value !=''){
                let name=a.value;
                let content=c.value;
                console.log(name);
                console.log(content);
                let jnameurl=JSON.stringify(name);
                let jcontenturl=JSON.stringify(content);
                let jname= new XMLHttpRequest();
                let jcontent = new XMLHttpRequest();
                jname.open('POST',jnameurl,'content.json',false);
                jcontent.open('POST',jcontenturl,'content.json',false);;
                jname.send();
                jcontent.send();
                console.log(jname.status);
                console.log(jcontent.status);
                console.log(jname.statusText);
                console.log(jcontent.statusText);
                console.log(jname.responseText);
                console.log(jcontent.responseText);
            }
            else {
            alert('you not write to input ');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Задача отправить данные полученные из input в файл .json чтобы потом с ним работать в Django.

Comment: `jname.open('POST','/saveToJson',true); jname.send(jnameurl);` - вы отправляете запрос с данными на back (/saveToJson - ссылка куда отправлять,true - синхронный/асинхронный запрос, по умолчанию он true) а он уже записывает их в файл. Нельзя отправить запрос сразу в файл

Comment: А можете тогда написать как надо сделать просто не очень понимаю json использую лишь для получения информации от пользователя.

Comment: или надо сначала отправить на сервер чтобы потом записать в файл, тогда как это реализовать в плане сервера php вообще не знаю.

Comment: А с чего он должен быть не 0? Статус надо проверять внутри `onreadystatechange`

Comment: Можно поподробнее

Comment: [_Before the request completes, the value of status is 0. Browsers also report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status)

Comment: Спасибо, а как мне реализовать запись в .json файл как я понимаю там нужен server.php а что в нём тогда писать?